# Let's Encrypt: SSL Certificate is valid for the Domain but not valid Specific Port

Tags: ssl, tomcat, amazon-ec2, port, lets-encrypt

I am using VPS: Amazon EC2 and SSL Cert Provider: Let's Encrypt (through Certbot)

I have seen some kind of a question but the answer is not useful for my situation.
I have a domain `api.example.com` that is configured and fully functioning on an Ubuntu server. I used Certbot to configure the domain with HTTPS, however, I also have APIs configured to be accessed on a specific port of that domain, say 8443.

When I access api.example.com, I see the lock on the browser that says the site is secure, but whenever I try to access my api `api.example.com:8443/v1/someAPI`, the API returns the appropriate result, but without the site is secure. Because the main site is secure, while the API access location isn't, I am unable to make API calls accordingly, resulting in `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

`Myapplication.java`

```
package com.xxx.xxxx;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
        System.setProperty("server.port", "8080");
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args); 
    }

}
```

my `application.properties`:

```
# Database
db.driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url: jdbc:mysql://123.123.123.123:123/ex?serverTimeZone=UTC&useSSL=false
db.username: xx
#db.password: xxx
db.password: xxxxxx
 
# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql: false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
hibernate.format_sql = false
entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.example

# GZIP Server compression
server.compression.enabled: true
server.compression.min-response-size: 2048
server.compression.mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain

# File Path
file.path: /home/ec2-user/
file.report.path: /home/ec2-user/
jpa.repositories.enabled=false

multipart.enabled=true
multipart.max-file-size=50MB
multipart.max-request-size=50MB

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB

# server base path
base.path: https://api.example.com:8443

# Origins to allow requests from
origins: *

#Error Page Configuration
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration

reportUrl:https://example.com/report/
email=contact@example.com
emails=sales@contact@example.com

# SMTP Configuration
spring.mail.enabled=true
spring.mail.from=sales@contact@example.com
##Amazon SES SMTP config
spring.mail.host=email-smtp 
spring.mail.username=fsdfskfjsldfjf
spring.mail.password=ffdfsfdsfdsfsdfdsf
spring.mail.port=123

eds.users: sales@marketsresearcher.biz
eds.host: smtp.gmail.com
eds.port: 123
eds.fromname==example

##SSL details
server.port:8443
security.require-ssl=true

server.ssl.key-store:classpath:abc.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password:abc
server.ssl.keyStoreType:PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias:abc
```

I have also added a rule for `8443` port in `aws ec2 instance security group`
[image]

I am getting an error on server log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2021-08-28 15:47:04.463  INFO 4513 --- [           main] c.a.MarketResearcher.ApplicationWar      : Starting ApplicationWar v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_302 on ip-172-31-17-203.ap-south-1.compute.internal with PID 4513 (/home/ec2-user/MarketResearcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /home/ec2-user)
2021-08-28 15:47:04.467  INFO 4513 --- [           main] c.a.MarketResearcher.ApplicationWar      : The following profiles are active: prod
2021-08-28 15:47:06.924  INFO 4513 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b39d77f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-08-28 15:47:07.008  INFO 4513 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2021-08-28 15:47:07.705  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https)
2021-08-28 15:47:07.729  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-08-28 15:47:07.730  INFO 4513 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-08-28 15:47:07.852  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-08-28 15:47:07.852  INFO 4513 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3164 ms
2021-08-28 15:47:08.432  INFO 4513 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
2021-08-28 15:47:08.894  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-08-28 15:47:09.462  INFO 4513 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2021-08-28 15:47:09.613  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2021-08-28 15:47:12.758  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-08-28 15:47:13.322  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-08-28 15:47:15.192  INFO 4513 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) with context path ''
2021-08-28 15:47:15.223  INFO 4513 --- [           main] c.a.MarketResearcher.ApplicationWar      : Started ApplicationWar in 11.771 seconds (JVM running for 12.677)
2021-08-28 15:52:41.387  INFO 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-08-28 15:52:41.388  INFO 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-08-28 15:52:41.390  INFO 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-08-28 16:06:33.275  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:33.391  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:33.683  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:33.738  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:33.739  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:33.747  WARN 4513 --- [io-8443-exec-10] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:33.845  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:33.866  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-28 16:06:34.021  WARN 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-7] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2021-08-29 19:08:38.141  INFO 4513 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [RTSP/1.00x0d0x0a0x0d...]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:559) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_302]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_302]
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure but can we use NAT Gateway to resolve this ?

Comment: You need to configure the http server that is hosting your API in the same way as your working application server is. Try to find a clue in your API server logs. Looks like it receives HTTPS request but unable to server it because of improperly configured keystore..

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of separate SSL for ports. Whenever the user enters `https://api.example.com`, the browser translates it as `api.example.com:443` and sends the request to the server.

Similarly, when you hit `http://api.example.com`, it's translated to `api.example.com:80`. The port for SSL (HTTPS) is `443`. The default port for HTTP is `80`.

In your case, if you use the `8443` port explicitly, SSL won’t work. Probably, you can host in 443 and route the API internally.

Comment: but the api   `example.com:8443/v1/someAPI` with the port number was valid with the SSL before...this time I am just renewing the SSL cert...can you help ?

Comment: Did you place the updated SSL certificate in the locations correctly? Refer to https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/ part 2 of the blog for more details.

Comment: incorrect, just type h.ttps://api.example.com:8843 as the url to send request to port 8843 with HTTPS encryption

Comment: @MikeMoy that wont work

Comment: what makes you say that ?

Answer (score 1):

create a virtual host for port 8843

```
<VirtualHost *:8843>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DocumentRoot /xxx/xxx/xxx

  <Directory /xxx/xxx/xxx>
   Require All Granted
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.pem"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.pem"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you give the commands for it??
Do I need to create the virtual host on my server  ec2-user where I hosted  the application

Comment: you would add this to your apache config file i.e. httpd.conf or apache2.conf, etc